# Xcode Errors Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, undefined, helper

Hey guys can you help this happened when i imported my project from another computer and i have no clue what to do? please help me.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Barbaraderoover/Desktop/BizCards-localCopy/Mitek     Hackathon/misnapsdk/libMiSnap.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/Barbaraderoover/Desktop/BizCards-localCopy/Mitek Hackathon/misnapsdk/libMiSnap.a (3 slices)
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MiSnapViewController", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in CardViewController.o
      "_kMiSnapAllowVideoFrames", referenced from:
          -[CardViewController takeButtonPressed:] in CardViewController.o
      "_kMiSnapMIPServerVersion", referenced from:
          -[CardViewController takeButtonPressed:] in CardViewController.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: u r missed the CardViewController file check that it is comes or not

Comment: No the CardViewController file is there

Comment: right clk the file and check u have .h and .m file is available or not in the location

Comment: just delete file and again once

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either libMiSnap.a is missing or the previous configured path is now invalid.
Try below:

1. Find if you can find libMiSnap.a in your source folder. If not find in previous computer.
2. Add again in Target build phases-> Link Binary with Libraries.
   3.clean your Project and run again

Comment: I see. so how do you get this libMiSnap? is this a 3rd party lib or you generate in your as static lib and than link ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response. But this might help some one in future. 
Try changing the deployment target to 6.0. It works good for me.